# Concat of all data frame columns using fold, reduce with Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following works fine with a dynamic column generation:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val input = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("a", "5a", "7w", "9", "a12", "a13") 
   )).toDF("ID", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5")

val columns_to_concat = input.columns
input.select(concat(columns_to_concat.map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concat_column")).show(false)
```

returns:

```
+-------------+
|concat_column|
+-------------+
|a5a7w9a12a13 |
+-------------+
```

How can I do this with **foldLeft, reduceLeft** - whilst retaining the dynamic column generation?

I always get either an error, or a null value returned. Whilst concat suffices, I am curious as to how fold, etc. could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It is definitely not the way to go**, but if you treat it as a programming exercise:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat, lit}

columns_to_concat.map(col(_)).reduce(concat(_, _))
```

or

```
columns_to_concat.map(col(_)).foldLeft(lit(""))(concat(_, _))
```

---

* Because

- It is a convoluted solution for something that already is provided by a high level API.
- Because it requires additional work from the planner / optimizer to flatten recursive expression, not to mention that the expression don't use tail call recursion and can simply overflow.